# Standard metric on adjoint bundle

Tags: fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

Consider we have a principal $G$-bundle $P$ over a closed manifold $V$. Denote $\mathfrak{g}_P$ by the associated bundle $P\times_G \mathfrak{g}$ where $G$ acts by adjoint action. Denote $\mathscr{G}$ by the gauge group.

For the following statement,
[image]

I wonder what is the standard $L^2$ metric on space of 1-forms with values in adjoint bundle. Since it seems to me we need a fiberwise metric on the adjoint bundle to define it, but I don't see the "standard choice".

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but if you take a Killing form on the Lie algebra that is invariant under the conjugation action $G$ on Lie($G$), that gives an fiber metric on the adjoint bundle. One typical example for $U(n)$-bundles (such as bundles of unitary frames) would be the trace $A,B\mapsto tr(AB)$ on $\mathfrak{u}(n)$.

Comment: If your $G$ is compact you can probably cook up a bilinear form on the Lie algebra such that it is conjugation invariant (call it $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle $ by averaging out a non-invariant one $(\cdot,\cdot)$:

$$
\langle A,B\rangle := \frac{1}{vol(G)} \int_G (gAg^{-1},gBg^{-1}) dg
$$

Comment: @topolosaurus I think you are right. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @topolosaurus But by kiliing form we get a complex valued bilinear form, to really have a metric, seems like we need to define a variation of it. Like for $\mathfrak{u}(n)$-bundles we use $tr(A^*B)$.

Comment: You are right, the trace metric I gave above is negative-definite on $\mathfrak{u}(n)$. In the case of $G$ being a **complex** Lie group I'd suggest to tread lightly, since they are very often not compact (unless they are torii). Note that $tr(A^*B)$ is a **real** inner product on the **real** vector space $\mathfrak{u}(n)$! Also note that $U(n)$ is **not** a complex Lie group, even though elements in it are complex matrices it is not a complex manifold (example, $U(1)$ is real 1-dimensional).

Comment: @topolosaurus Thanks for the comment!